# Warning while installing npm

Tags: node.js, npm

While executing the following command :

```
npm install
```

i'm getting the following error :

```
npm WARN kibana_api@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN kibana_api@0.1.0 No license field.
```

Please help me on how to resolve the above warning.

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about these warning. The problem here i feel is that kibana_api doesn't have licence file in the package, but this should not do you any harm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `kibana_api` is your own project, you can remove those warnings by adding a [`repository`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository) and a [`license`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#license) field to [`package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

However, they are just warnings, and you may not even have a repository or a license for your project, or `kibana_api` isn't your own project (i.e. it's just a *dependency* of your project). In that case, just ignore them.